# Search result page navigation by either click enter or click img

Tags: search

```
I want to search content with search keyword and it should navigate to search result page.

Can you please correct them to achieve search functionality in EE either by clicking enter or click searchimage..

<form id="search" class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.2s" action="search.php" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
{exp:search:simple_form channel="news" name="" result_page="news/searches"}
              <input name="s" type="text" value="Search "/> 
              <a onclick="document.getElementById('search').submit()">
                <img src="/images/search.png" alt=""/>
              </a>
{/exp:search:simple_form}
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh.. `submit()` is a jQuery bind, not native JavaScript.

```
$('.your-img-class').click(function(){
    $('submit[name="your_submit_button_name"]').submit();
});
```